# How to change the size of the header part of the liferay?

Tags: css, liferay

[image: that is the screenshot of the current system. I want the header to go upa bit with a reduced size, so that i can move the menu and hence move the document portlet up and visible for the end user]i want to change the size of the header of the Liferay portal page through css.How do i achieve this? i also want to change the color of the menu.

Comment: Can you post the code of the header? or a live link of the portal?

Comment: i am sorry, due to security concerns, i am not allowed to put the live link of the portal.

Comment: il add a screenshot..

Comment: How can we help you then? :) We need to see your code. Just post the header CSS, HTML code.

Comment: @ManojKumar : rite now i am using the default theme and css of Lifreay. I have not added any code.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays every browser has some Firebug-style developer tools. E.g. on Firefox, hit F12 and the tool will open at the bottom of the page. Choose the "Inspector" (labels might vary, I'm looking at the german UI), find the "choose an element of the page" button, then point your mouse to the area of the page that you want to explore the CSS. You'll see how the appropriate part of the DOM is selected in the inspector and even the actual CSS rules that apply. You can temporarily change the CSS there and try out what values you actually want.

Next, learn [how to build a theme](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-a-theme-project-in-the-plugins-sdk) in Liferay. You'll add the required CSS, identified in the step above, in your theme's custom.css.

Yes, this isn't the actual CSS that you need (probably you just wanted to know that single line), but your next question would be on how to change a different aspect of the default theme - this is how you can find it out and even solve other theme-related problems that you didn't even think of yet.

Comment: sir, i tried to change the css. but its not reflecting in the page.

Comment: i changed it through the custom css

Comment: Did you build a new theme? Or did you just change custom.css on the server? The later option will not work, as CSS is minified, combined into one single file. This is redone when you actually deploy a new theme, but not when you change random files on the server.

Comment: i dint build a new theme, i just changed it through the custom css.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific: "I changed *something* and it didn't work" causes me to answer "You'll need to change *something else*" which won't help you. Also, the developer tools will also tell you if your CSS is active but overridden by some more specific CSS (right-hand side of the tool where you see the CSS for the selected element in the DOM, with striked-out declarations that are overridden by others)